# String pointer, count ammount of letter in word

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I have something like this :

```
typedef struct
{
    char *Word;
    char *Meaning;
} par;

Par Something[][].Word;
```

And I have to count how much consonants is in that word.
I really don't understand how can I count them....
I know how to do with a simple array of char, but apparentlly it isn't the same...

EDIT:
sorry, I forgot to post whole things, now it's like it really is... ^^

Comment: `string` is an array so you can use `string[index_number]` to read a particular element of the array (a character).  Wrap this in a `for` or `while` loop and you can iterate over each character in your string, performing whatever processing you like on each character.

Answer (score 0):

To access the pointer elements of string, use *(string+i) and iterate i through while or for loop from `0 to length(string)`

Answer (score 0):

When you know how to do it with an array

```
char string[] = "basic";
int i;
for (i = 0; string[i] != 0; ++i) {
    /* count consonants */
}
```

you also know how to do it with a char pointer

```
char *string = "basic";
int i;
for (i = 0; string[i] != 0; ++i) {
    /* count consonants */
}
```

With a char pointer, you have other options, of course

```
char *string = "basic";
char *p;
for (p = string; *p != 0; ++p) {
    /* count consonants */
}
```